# SharedUserId access SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I got two apps, with these package names:

- com.blah.a
- com.blah.b

They got the sharedUserId "com.blah.shared". At /data/data in my device they both got a folder with there data, which contains the shared_prefs folder and the default SharedPreferences files named:

- com.blah.a_preferences.xml
- com.blah.b_preferences.xml

I know that two apps with the same sharedUserId can access each others files. **How can I read app a's SharedPreferences from app b?**

I found one solution, but it is neither working well (if app a updates a preference, app b still reads the old value) nor good code (can throw exception).

```
try {
    Context c = context.createPackageContext("com.blah.a", 
        Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY))

    aPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't need to do this, and `sharedUserId` is a bad idea for production apps. In any case, this is the code to do it, but you don't need to specify `IGNORE_SECURITY`. If your apps have the same UID, they should be able to read each other's (private) files. As for the exception, an exception will only be thrown if the package doesn't exists. You could check if it does, and only execute the code if it exists (i.e., the other app is installed). There is probably some caching, so you should load the prefs each time you need them.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. I'll try to get it working with this method. Why is sharedUserId a bad idea for production apps?

Comment: I tested a little bit more. Even if I load the preference directly before i read it, it isn't updated. Because the method isn't reliable I will save the values into a single-row table in my ContentProvider. Still would like to now why sharedUserId is a bad idea...

Comment: ContentProvider sounds good, you can have fine-grained control over what data to expose. As for sharedUserId, apparently it was originally intended for system apps only. Quote: 'It will have a lot of subtle repercussions on your app that you may not like -- everything from all of the apps with the same shared user ID being batched together in accounting for battery use, to your processes being killed when one of your apps with the shared user ID is updated.'

Comment: Are you apps already published? If so, you might want to take care and do thorough testing. If add or remove the sharedUserId, the UID of the app will change, and it will not be able to read its own data. There might be other problems as well.

Comment: They are still in development, so that is no problem. But thanks for the reminder :)